# Утилита для неявных преобразования C++

Tags: c++

Может ли кто подсказать утилиту linux для выявления всех неявных преобразований в коде? Желательно с объяснением, как ее использовать?

Comment: может быть Вы просто хотите узнать о clang-tidy и параметрах gcc `-Wall -pedantic -Wextra` ?

Comment: может быть, я не знаю. я использую на линукс Qtcreator и Cmake.

Comment: добавьте себе в cmake такую строку `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pedantic -Wextra")`

Comment: Добавил, скомпилировал, а дальше что делать?

Comment: Опция, включающая предупреждения для потенциально некорректных преобразований это `-Wconversion`. С параметрами `-Wall -pedantic -Wextra` она остается отключена. Возможность выявления всех неявных преобразований отсутствует. Во всяком случае, о готовых инструментах я не слышал..

Comment: это все параметры заставляют компилятор генерировать больше предупреждений, среди которых есть и нужные о преобразованиях. Да, компилятор нужно поновее. если это gcc 2.9, то много с него не получишь